# Parse serialized json payload in java

Tags: java, android, json

im struggling with json again :( 
Here is the original response:

```
{"xml-fragment":{"workItem":{"@id":"251","@version":"74"},"presentation":{"@formIdenitifier":"1.0.0.201310151421/openspaceGWTPull_DefaultChannel/.default/Npda/NpdaProcess/UserReconcile/UserReconcile.gwt.json","@type":"GWT_FORM","@version":"1.0.0.201310151421","@activityName":"UserReconcile"},"workTypeDetail":{"@typePiled":"false","@pilingLimit":"0","@uid":"WT__RIoPEDWTEeOr4-yR8gXd7g","@version":"1.0.0.201310151421"},"payloadModel":{"serializedPayload":"{items:[{\"$param\":\"BankReconInput\",\"mode\":\"IN\",\"$value\":[{\"bankAccountTx_pk\":\"55213\",\"amount\":\"10099\",\"reference\":\"ImAmReference\",\"date\":\"2013-10-15\",\"reconType\":\"?\",\"amxcaseref\":\"pvm:0a12iq\",\"$type\":\"coza.npda.bom.BankTransaction\"}]}]}","@payloadMode":"JSON"}}}
```

i want to for example get value of amount from the serializedPayload. The problem is that it is not a json object. If i try:

```
obj = new JSONObject(jsonResp).getJSONObject("xml-fragment").getJSONObject("payloadModel");
```

this returns to me serializedPayload as a string and @payloadMode as a string.

i tried:

```
obj = new JSONObject(jsonResp).getJSONObject("xml-fragment").getJSONObject("payloadModel").getJSONObject("serializedPayload");
```

its confirms that serializedPayload  is not a json object.

I looked at this example: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html
But its data is not as complex as mine and i am struggling to find java examples of how to do this.

Please can anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an example, you need to look at the JSON and think for a second.

**serializedPayload is not a JSON object to begin with**, it's really a string that has another piece of json encoded inside, sort of like the russian nesting dolls (frankly, it's an abomination).

You need to take the string, and then parse it again, using another JSONObject, sort of:

```
String payload = data..getJSONObject("xml-fragment").getJSONObject("payloadModel").getString("serializedPayload");
JSONObject theRealData = new JSONObject(payload);
```